# How to pull data moving backwards in a java ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I am trying to make it so I can write data to a ArrayList to track random integers and then I will have a previous button that will go back to the last result (This is just testing that code this is not the full code for the project) I am getting an error when trying to take the int arraySize and subtract it by 1 and reprint the data. Any idea why this is happening or how another way to accomplish the task.

```
int lenth = 10;
ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
int arraySize = list.size();
Random random = new Random();
int newRandom = random.nextInt(lenth);
list.add(newRandom);
newRandom = random.nextInt(lenth);
list.add(newRandom);
System.out.println(list.get(arraySize));
arraySize--;
System.out.println(list.get(arraySize));
```

Also here is the error I am getting:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
at java.util.ArrayList.elementData(Unknown Source)
at java.util.ArrayList.get(Unknown Source)
at test.C_MainActivity.main(C_MainActivity.java:22)
```

Comment: By listArray, do you mean `ArrayList`?

Comment: Index start from 0. So, if you have 3 elements, last element will be at index `2` and not at `3`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you assign one [primitive](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) (such as an `int`) to another, this copies the value to the new variable. For objects, this works a bit differently in that these variables will point to the same object.

```
int arraySize = list.size();
```

So the above line will just set `arraySize` to the current size of the list, `arraySize` will not change as the list size changes. Since you do this when the list is empty, it will be and remain `0` and you'll try to get the elements at indices `0` and `0-1 = -1`, which is where your exception comes in.

You should just set it after you've inserted all elements instead.

---

Note that indexing in Java starts at 0, so the last element will already be at `list.size() - 1`, not `list.size()`.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting arraySize before anything has been added to the list. The value of arraySize will always be 0 because you only set it at the beginning. When you call arraySize--, arraySize is now -1 and when you call list.get(arraySize), you will get an index out of bound exception as you are asking for index -1.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your goal is to enqueue values in a collection and then dequeue them. A `LinkedList`, for example, would be more appropriate with its `push()` and `pop()` methods.

Anyway you should not keep track of the `ArrayList`'s size through an external variable. Such data is already provided for you inside `ArrayList` so you just have to query the list to know its size.